# Перенос радиокнопок в модальное окно

Tags: jquery

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Цель задачи: перенести `<input type="radio" />` в модальное окно, чтоб результат их нажатия остался там же.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.mdl#m4").hide();
  $("input[name$='group9']").click(function() {
    var test = $(this).val();
    $("div.mdl").hide();
    $("#" + test).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>
  <br/>
  <input id='select1' type='radio' name='group9' value='g5' test>
  <label for='select1'>Гранит</label>
</div>
<div>
  <br/>
  <input id='select1' type='radio' name='group9' value='m4' test>
  <label for='select1'>Мрамор"</label>
</div>
<div id="g5" class="mdl">
  <b>Модель:</b>
  <span class="select_name">Модель №1</span>
  <span class="select_edit">Гранит</span>
  <br/>
</div>

<div id="m4" class="mdl">
  <b>Модель:</b>
  <span class="select_name">Модель №1</span>
  <span class="select_edit">Мрамор</span>
  <br/>
</div>
```

Comment: А какая разница где они?  В чем суть вопроса?

Comment: У меня на сайте(тематика памятники) есть две кнопки Изменить: 1 меняет материал, 2 меняет модель. Обе кнопки вызывают модальное окно. Если нажать первую то там две радиокнопки Мрамор и Гранит. Во второй куча моделей резки памятников, но они не совпадают с выбранными материалами. Поэтом пришлось сделать ещё одну кнопку Изменить для моделей мрамора которая по задумке скрыта, но стоит перевести переключатель в первом окне на мрамор, как она открывается, а гранит скрывается. Так происходит если выбор моделей находиться не в модальном окне. Как сохранить значение радиокнопки нажатой в модальномокне

Comment: Под вопросом, кнопка править, нажми ее о переформулируй вопрос.  Лично я понял, что я ничего не понял...

Comment: Добавил картинку, нужно чтоб значение радиокнопки запоминалось, и возвращалось из модального окна заменяя строчку Модель. Я просто не знаю уже как объяснить.

Comment: Если не понятно с картинками, то можно удалить вопрос тогда...